# How to define public and private property in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, oop

I want to define public and private property in JavaScript class,

Here you see c# format of my properties.

My question is 'How can I write these properties with JavaScript':

```
public class MyMath
{
    public static double Pi 
    {
       get {return 3.14;}
    }

    public static int R {get; set;}

    private int MyPrivateProp1 {get; set;}

    public double MyCalcMethod()
    {
           return MyPrivateProp1 * R;
    }
}
```

I want to use this class like:

```
var x = MyMath.Pi * MyMath.R;
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Where is your private prop?

Comment: @Simsons, JavaScript has strong object-oriented programming capabilities. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: @mini-me You can create private variables within a function that cannot be referenced externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `self-executing` function to create your object, this will then allow you to instantly call the variables and methods from your Javascript without having to create an instance of the object.

Example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/gFXpA/)

```
var myMath = (function MyMath() {
    this.Pi = 3.14;
    this.R = 0;

    var MyPrivateProp1 = 15;

    this.MyCalcMethod = function() {
      return R * MyPrivateProp1;
    };

    return this;
})();

myMath.R = 5;

var x = myMath.Pi * myMath.R;

console.log(myMath.Pi);
console.log(myMath.R);
console.log(myMath.MyPrivateProp1); //This is returned as Undefined because it is a Private Variable to the Object.
console.log(myMath.MyCalcMethod());
console.log(x);
```

Notice the `return this` at the end of the function, this is required to ensure the object is passed to the `myMath` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is closures.

```
var Person = function () {
    var localVariable = "I'm hidden";

    this.publicProperty = "example";

    this.publicFunction = function () {
        // This function has access to the localVariable
        // but nothing outside can get to it directly.
        console.log(localVariable);
        return "aren't I clever?";
    }
};

Person.prototype.staticProperty = "A banana";
```

Now you can create an instance of your person class:

```
var aPerson = new Person();
console.log(aPerson.publicProperty);
console.log(aPerson.publicFunction());
console.log(aPerson.staticProperty);
console.log(aPerson.localVaraible) // undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object which would store the two variables.

Example:

```
var MyMath = {}; //Create a new object
MyMath.Pi = 3.14;
MyMath.R = function(value){
    if(value !== undefined){
        this.val=value;
    }// Set
        else return this.val //Get

};
```

And you could use it like you wanted:

```
var x = MyMath.Pi * MyMath.R(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  // define the MyMathClass
    function MyMath() {
        function MyPrivateProp1(){
        //Define get set;
        }
    }
    MyMath.prototype.Pi  = function(){
    //Define get
      return 3.14;
    };

    MyMath.prototype.R = function(){
    //Define get and set
    };


    var MyMath = new MyMath();
    var x = MyMath.Pi() * MyMath.R();
```

References.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide
http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/